# no almacena la variable $_SESSION en php

Tags: php, mysql

> SESSION.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('conexion.php');
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$tabla = $_POST['tabla'];
switch ($tabla) {
    case 'docentes':
      $getUsuario = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE email='$usuario' AND clave='$clave'") or die ('error al obtener datos de usuarios');
    break;
    case 'alumnos':
      $getUsuario = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE matricula='$usuario' AND clave='$clave'") or die ('error al obtener datos de usuarios');
    break;
}

$row_cnt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsuario);
if ($row_cnt != "") {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($getUsuario,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['tipo'] = $tabla;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['ID']; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< No se almacena
    $_SESSION['logeo'] = 1;

}else{
  echo "false";
}
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

> Panel control

```
   <?php
  include('php/conexion.php');
  //$login=20;
  session_start();
  error_reporting(0);

  $login=$_SESSION['usuario'];
  if ($login == null || $login == '') {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
  }
...................................
```

no se almacena nada en $_SESSION['usuario'] ... no entiendo cual podría ser el error.

> ACTUALIZACION

al parecer el problema viene de aquí.

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($getUsuario,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    /*$_SESSION['tipo'] = $tabla;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['ID']; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< No se almacena
    $_SESSION['logeo'] = 1;*/
    if ($row['ID'] != null) {
      $_SESSION['tipo'] = $tabla;
      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['ID']; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< No se almacena
      $_SESSION['logeo'] = 1;
      echo ($row['nombre']);
  }else{
    echo "false";
  }
```

esta modificacion y con el **echo** mostrando lo que trae el valor ID, funciona perfecto el problema es lo mismo la variable row si trae informacion pero SESSION no la almacena.

Comment: Realmente este es el `id` del usuario así : **ID**

Comment: es mi ID de usuario, del que se busca

Comment: todo parece estar bien, debes verificar que los datos que estás enviando del formulario este escrito en `name` de la misma forma (usuario)

Comment: Haz un `echo` de `$row['ID'];` y comprueba que tenga datos realmente. PD: No se almacena valor, o no se crea la variable?

Comment: si hace el query perfect, los datos los esta obteniendo del query no de formulario. el problema es que la demás información si se almacena correctamente. puse un **echo** para ver que estaba resolviendo la variable $row['ID']; y si trae la información correcta. solo SESSION que no quiere almacenar o solo que sea una sintaxis mala.

Comment: correccion. el echo no me muestra nada de $row['ID'];

Comment: al parecer el problema viene de **$row_cnt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsuario);
if ($row_cnt != "") {** pero no entiendo como podria validar eso de otra forma.

Comment: Deberías activar los errores `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` y hacer comprobaciones.. que las querys y los resultados sean correctamente

Comment: hola que tal he editado el codigo para esta parte.

Comment: @ManuelMorales ahora dices que los datos los traes desde el `query` y no de un formulario... Que raro porque si fuera así deberías añadir un valor por defaul a la variable `$usuario = 1;` o al menos que esté tomando el `id` de usuario que ya esté logueado en el sistema...

Comment: lo hago con ajax, envio los parametros $_POST de usuario y clave, eso no es problema.

Comment: @ManuelMorales pues al parecer no lo está recibiendo, has lo que dijo **aldanux** comenta // las advertencias de PHP para saber que error te lanza... No es buena idea desactivarlos al menos que el proyecto ya esté completo y se haya verificado que no existan errores.